Hyperledger Fabric Orderer: Channel join fails with BFT (V3_0): Status 400
Error message:
invalid join block: initializing channelconfig failed: could not create channel Orderer sub-group config: setting up the MSP manager failed: the supplied identity is not valid: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
Call:
osnadmin channel join             --channelID EA --config-block /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/configuration/EA/genesis_block.pb             -o 172.25.3.11:53113             --ca-file /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/_Admin/tls/tlscacerts/tls-tls-jedo-dev-51031.pem --client-cert /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/_Admin/Nik/tls/signcerts/cert.pem --client-key /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/_Admin/Nik/tls/keystore/7ae0d1f58f1c30e3b7dd2b272df0385c99487c44aabf9adf4dee63a05825b54a_sk

Orderer Log:
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0078 DEBU [common.channelconfig] NewStandardValues -> Initializing protos for *channelconfig.ChannelProtos
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0079 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: HashingAlgorithm
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 007a DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: BlockDataHashingStructure
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 007b DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: OrdererAddresses
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 007c DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: Orderers
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 007d DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: Consortium
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 007e DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: Capabilities
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 007f DEBU [common.channelconfig] NewStandardValues -> Initializing protos for *channelconfig.OrdererProtos
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0080 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: ConsensusType
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0081 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: BatchSize
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0082 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: BatchTimeout
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0083 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: KafkaBrokers
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0084 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: ChannelRestrictions
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0085 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: Orderers
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0086 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: Capabilities
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0087 DEBU [common.channelconfig] NewStandardValues -> Initializing protos for *channelconfig.OrdererOrgProtos
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0088 DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: Endpoints
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0089 DEBU [common.channelconfig] NewStandardValues -> Initializing protos for *channelconfig.OrganizationProtos
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 008a DEBU [common.channelconfig] initializeProtosStruct -> Processing field: MSP
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 008b DEBU [common.channelconfig] validateMSP -> Setting up MSP for org ALPS
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 008c DEBU [msp] newBccspMsp -> Creating BCCSP-based MSP instance
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 008d DEBU [msp] New -> Creating Cache-MSP instance
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 008e DEBU [msp] Setup -> Setting up MSP instance ALPS
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 008f DEBU [msp.identity] newIdentity -> Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----
2024-12-28 14:23:04.920 UTC 0090 DEBU [msp.identity] newIdentity -> Creating identity instance for cert -----BEGIN CERTIFICATE-----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-----END CERTIFICATE-----

configty.yaml:
---
Organizations:
  - &ALPS
    Name: ALPS
    ID: ALPS
    MSPDir: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/ALPS/msp
    Policies: &ALPSPolicies
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ALPS.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ALPS.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ALPS.admin')"
      BlockValidation:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('ALPS.member')"
    OrdererEndpoints:
      - orderer.alps.ea.jedo.dev:53111
  - &JURA
    Name: JURA
    ID: JURA
    MSPDir: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/JURA/msp
    Policies: &JURAPolicies
      Readers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('JURA.member')"
      Writers:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('JURA.member')"
      Admins:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('JURA.admin')"
      BlockValidation:
        Type: ImplicitMeta
        Rule: "ANY Writers"
      Endorsement:
        Type: Signature
        Rule: "OR('JURA.member')"
    OrdererEndpoints:
      - orderer.jura.ea.jedo.dev:54111
Capabilities:
  Channel: &ChannelCapabilities
    V3_0: true
  Orderer: &OrdererCapabilities
    V2_0: true
  Application: &ApplicationCapabilities
    V2_5: true
Application: &ApplicationDefaults
  Organizations:
    - *ALPS
    - *JURA
  Policies: &ApplicationDefaultPolicies
    LifecycleEndorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Endorsement:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "MAJORITY Endorsement"
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Admins"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ApplicationCapabilities
Orderer: &OrdererDefaults
  OrdererType: BFT
  BatchTimeout: 2s
  BatchSize:
    MaxMessageCount: 500
    AbsoluteMaxBytes: 10 MB
    PreferredMaxBytes: 2 MB
  MaxChannels: 0
  SmartBFT:
    RequestBatchMaxInterval: 200ms
    RequestForwardTimeout: 5s
    RequestComplainTimeout: 20s
    RequestAutoRemoveTimeout: 3m0s
    ViewChangeResendInterval: 5s
    ViewChangeTimeout: 20s
    LeaderHeartbeatTimeout: 1m0s
    CollectTimeout: 1s
    IncomingMessageBufferSize: 200
    RequestPoolSize: 100000
    LeaderHeartbeatCount: 10
  ConsenterMapping:
    - ID: 1
      Host: orderer.alps.ea.jedo.dev
      Port: 53111
      MSPID: ALPS
      Identity: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/ALPS/orderer.alps.ea.jedo.dev/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
      ClientTLSCert: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/ALPS/orderer.alps.ea.jedo.dev/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      ServerTLSCert: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/ALPS/orderer.alps.ea.jedo.dev/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
    - ID: 2
      Host: orderer.jura.ea.jedo.dev
      Port: 54111
      MSPID: JURA
      Identity: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/JURA/orderer.jura.ea.jedo.dev/msp/signcerts/cert.pem
      ClientTLSCert: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/JURA/orderer.jura.ea.jedo.dev/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
      ServerTLSCert: /mnt/user/appdata/jedo-dev/infrastructure/JEDO/EA/JURA/orderer.jura.ea.jedo.dev/tls/signcerts/cert.pem
  Organizations:
    - *ALPS
    - *JURA
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Admins"
    BlockValidation:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *OrdererCapabilities
Channel: &ChannelDefaults
  Policies:
    Readers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Readers"
    Writers:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Writers"
    Admins:
      Type: ImplicitMeta
      Rule: "ANY Admins"
  Capabilities:
    <<: *ChannelCapabilities
Profiles:
  JedoChannel:
    <<: *ChannelDefaults
    Consortium: EA
    Orderer:
      <<: *OrdererDefaults
      Organizations:
        - <<: *ALPS
          Policies:
            <<: *ALPSPolicies
            Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('ALPS.member')"
        - <<: *JURA
          Policies:
            <<: *JURAPolicies
            Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('JURA.member')"
    Application:
      <<: *ApplicationDefaults
      Organizations:
        - <<: *ALPS
          Policies:
            <<: *ALPSPolicies
            Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('ALPS.member')"
        - <<: *JURA
          Policies:
            <<: *JURAPolicies
            Admins:
              Type: Signature
              Rule: "OR('JURA.member')"

Who calls this error and why?
This some more useless text because so requests to safe this post...

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
